# knockoutjs data bind hidden field value

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, data-binding, hidden-field

I'm having a hidden field in a knockout template that its value gets updated with jquery. The problem is when trying to pass this value to the server with ajax, I get null value in the controller. But the html source code shows that the value of the hidden field is updated. If I replaced the hidden field with a textbox, it would work fine only when I enter text manually.

jQuery

```
        function getFileDetail(fileID, fileName) {
        $('#hdnFileName' + fileID).val(fileName);
        $('#lblFileName' + fileID).text(fileName);
    }
```

Here is the html knockout template:

```
    <script type="text/html" id="fileTemplate">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { openFileUpload('file', ID) }"><label data-bind="text: 'File Upload ' + ID, attr: { id: 'lblFileName' + ID }"></label></a><input type="button" value="Remove" data-bind="click: removeFile" /> 
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="hdnFileName" data-bind="attr: { id: 'hdnFileName' + ID, value: fileName }" />
    </script>
```

ViewModel

```
function FileViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = ko.observable();
        self.fileName = ko.observable();
        self.removeFile = function (file) { };
        self.Files = ko.observableArray([{ ID: 1, fileName: "", removeFile: function (file) { self.Files.remove(file); }}]);

        self.addNewFile = function () {
            var newFile = new FileViewModel();
            newFile.ID = self.Files().length + 1;
            newFile.fileName = "";
            newFile.removeFile = function (file) { self.Files.remove(file); };
            self.Files.push(newFile);
            //$("input[name='hdnFileName'").trigger("change");
        }
    }
function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.fileViewModel = new FileViewModel();
        self.submitForm = function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%= Url.Action("MeetingPresenter")%>",
                data: "{Files:" + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.fileViewModel.Files) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {},
            });
        };
    }
```

Comment: Where you insert the value with `jQuery`?

Comment: It seems odd that you're using an attr binding to bind value. Is there a reason you're not using the value binding?

Comment: @adricadar I just added the jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `knockout.js` you don't neede to modify the DOM, you can just update the `ViewModel` and the DOM will be updated according

```
function getFileDetail(fileID, fileName) {
    viewModel.fileViewModel.update(fileID, fileName);
}
```

Add the `update` function in `FileViewModel`

```
function FileViewModel() {
    // rest of the code

    self.update = function(fileID, fileName) {
        var file = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Files(), function(file) {
            return file.ID == fileID;
        });

        file.fileName(fileName); // this will change and the UI will be updated according
    };
}
```

**Note:** Please notice that you have a default item in `Files` that will not be changed with `update` function because properties are not `observable`

```
self.Files = ko.observableArray([{ ID: 1, fileName: "", removeFile: function (file) { self.Files.remove(file); }}]);
```

You can solve this by making them `observable` (i.e. `ID: observable(1)`) or you can create a `new FileViewModel()`.

**Note:** The `viewModel` must be accesible in the function (i.e. global instance), otherwise will be `undefined`.

Comment: I have added the update function to the FileViewModel, but for some reason file is having the value of null. Am I missing something?

Comment: @WS84 The idea there is to find the element that match the condition. You can find other ways to find the element that match that condition. Also you can put a brakepoin to make sure that `fileID` contains what you want and the array have that element.

Comment: It is working perfect now! I just had to create a global instance of the ViewModel(). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your model property `ID` is an observable, so you need to 'unwrap' to get the value from it when you are concatenating, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnFileName" data-bind="attr: { id: 'hdnFileName' + ID(), value: fileName }" />
```

and this:

```
<label data-bind="text: 'File Upload ' + ID(), attr: { id: 'lblFileName' + ID() }"></label>
```

Comment: Thanks David. But I tried this and it gave an error ID() is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that setting a field's value via the DOM does not interact with knockout. If you are setting its value using `.value`, the observable will not be updated. You should be updating the observable.

I wrote a little Fiddle to demonstrate. Every 2 seconds, it sets the input's value via the DOM, but the bound observable only changes when you type something.

http://jsfiddle.net/qcv01h2e/

```
var viewModel = (function () {
    return {
        fv: ko.observable().extend({notify:'always'})
    };
}());

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
setInterval(function () {
    console.debug("Set it");
    var f = document.getElementById('field');
    f.value = "Hi";
    console.debug("fv is", viewModel.fv());
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue where I need to set a value without user input. 
Before doing the click update function I do the required model update. If you have mode operations better to introduce a function in the model.

```
<input data-bind="click: function(){ isEnabled(true); update() }" />
```

What I actually did was,

```
<input data-bind="click: function(){ isEnabled(!isEnabled()); update() }" />
```

Keep in mind that asynchronous nature of javascript.